# Airplane travel with heavy music gear

Tags: travel

I have Pioneer DJ mixer that weighs 17 lbs.
along with an oddessey case that weighs 36 lbs.

And I want to dj for my cousin's wedding which is overseas but I'm not sure what would be a good way to bring the heavy music gear there.

One thought was to downgrade the mixer case to a mixer bag.

Any recommendation from experts musicians who carry heavy toolset overseas?

Comment: Is it possible to rent equipment in the country which you plan to play?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this in the "travel" section, but anyway, I think that it depends on every airplane company. In some of them you can pay some extra charges to put them in a safe place, with other music instruments or bikes, pets etc... Otherwise, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done this before -- my one time taking an instrument during travel, it was a POS acoustic I cared nearly nothing about -- but when I see musicians talk about short-trip travel, they tend to bring an instrument and a pedalboard and rent a back-line. I'd look into renting a DJ rig rather than travelling with your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could rent the equipment rather than taking it on the plane. Check out https://www.sparkplug.it. It's an instrument rental marketplace where you can rent gear from another musician.